# Convert an object to be immutable

Tags: c#, immutability

I had originally created a class that was not immutable, but now I want to have the option to make an immutable equivalent data structure.  Pretend, for example, the mutable class:

```
namespace Utility
{
    public class bar
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double weight { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set;}
        public List<...> friendInstances; //instantiated at run time
    }
}

  //and now I make a mutable class.

public class MemorySafe_bar
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly double _weight;
    private readonly int _age;
    private readonly List<...> _friendInstances;

    public MemorySafe_bar(string name, double weight, int age,
         List<...> friend Inst)
    {
        _name = name;
        _weight = weight;
        _age = age;
        _friendInstances = Inst
    }
    //..getters would go here...

    function()
    {
      Utility.bar bar_ex = new bar();
      bar_ex.name = "Kathy";
      bar_ex.weight = 42.34;
      bar_ex.age = 10;
      bar_ex.List<...> friends = new List<...>();
      friends.Add(stuff);

      Utility.MemorySafe_bar = new MemorySafe_bar(
        bar_ex.name, bar_ex.weight, bar_ex.age, friends);
    }
}
```

I do not believe the mutable object will ever be changed in the future from this point forward.

Comment: What exactly would you like explained? Also why not just set up a static class with a static constructor?

Comment: Tried to format your code, but there is that strange `function()` with unclear scope - please update code... Also add question to the post.

Comment: What is the question? Also, if an object is supposed to be truly immutable, all its members also have to be immutable, which means you can't use `List`.

Comment: @svick: If I had a nickel for every time I saw a reference to a `List<T>`/`IEnumerable<T>` passed in/out via the constructor, properties, or methods and the developer thought it was immutable... EDIT: In this case though, you _can_ use `List`, and the object is supposed to be truly immutable you _can_ use mutable members. You just have to control access to those members.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283109/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-create-an-immutable-class-in-c/15283232#15283232 for more information on C# and immutable classes

Comment: @svick, to be clear, and as Chris points out, to be immutable, all its members (outside of the constructor) need to avoid modification of internal state.  There are a wide variety of ways to achieve that, including using copies of lists, etc.  (and certainly the ideal implementation will in fact use `readonly`, etc. to more strongly enforce immutability within the class itself.)

Comment: I don't understand why it is downvoted. Sometimes I need to pass objects to methods as read only (there is no final or const keyword for method arguments in C#). Even though there are many ways to do that, the question isn't that bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for a general/reusable method of wrapping *any* class to be an immutable version, it's not really possible in a generic sense.

If a particular class exposed its members as `virtual` or `abstract` (or as an `interface`) you *could* create implementations that do nothing (or throw exceptions) on the setters, but this would generally be unexpected.

In your current case, I would first update the constructor to take the object you're wrapping, or do so through a static factory method. I would also store a local copy of the `friendInstances` and return a read-only enumerable of it:

```
public class ReadOnlyBar
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public double weight { get; private set; }
    public int age { get; private set; }

    private readonly Friend[] _friendInstances;

    public IEnumerable<Friend> friendInstances
    {
        get
        {
            foreach(var friend in _friendInstances)
                yield return friend;
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlyBar(Bar bar)
    {
        this.name = bar.name;
        this.weight = bar.weight;
        this.age = bar.age;
        this._friendInstances = bar.friendInstances.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage like:

```
Bar mutableBar = new mutableBar() { name="Kathy", .... };
ReadOnlyBar readonlyBar = new ReadOnlyBar(mutableBar);
```

I only kept the immutable Bar using properties instead of `readonly` fields simply to match the original `Bar`'s API as much as possible; these can be easily switched back to the fields (which would help enforce immutability against boneheaded coded within the class). You can also easily move the creation to static factory methods or extension methods so you might get usage like:

```
Bar mutableBar = new mutableBar() { name="Kathy", .... };
ReadOnlyBar readonlyBar = ReadOnlyBar.Create(mutableBar);
//or
ReadOnlyBar readonlyBar = mutableBar.MakeReadOnly();
```

EDIT: Another quick option if you want to maintain most of the functionality/members of `List<Friend>` and not degrade it to an `IEnumerable`, you could use this instead:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Friend> friendInstances { get; private set; }

public ReadOnlyBar(Bar bar)
{
    //other initialization
    this.friendInstances = bar.friendInstances.ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

Or you could even type is as `List<Friend>` and in the getter return a *copy* of the internal list, but that's probably going a bit far and is a confusing property to expose on an "immutable" object type.